Why does this A380 power outlet give 400Hz power?
Recently I found this image from the internet that shows a power outlet in the Airbus A380 and it has been labelled "115V - 400 Hz 1kVA max".
All of that makes sense apart from the 400 Hz part. Why is that? Wouldn't it be more useful if it provided 50 Hz or 60 Hz electricity that most appliances use?
What's the use of this outlet?
Is it because of something related to the APU generator?


Related: Why do aircraft use 400 Hz AC instead of the 50 or 60 Hz of wall outlets?, How common are 400Hz supplies in aircraft? and How does the A350/380 operate on Variable Frequency AC generators?

Is there a standard wall socket under there? All the photo shows is a cover plate, not a power outlet.

Because that's what planes use.

The use of the outlet is for vacuum cleaners for the cleaning crew.
Traditionally, large planes used 400 Hz power. Therefore infrastructure, namely ground power supply units and the vacuum cleaners that cleaning crew use are designed for 400 Hz.
The A380 uses a variable-frequency AC system where the frequency drifts from 360-800 Hz depending on engine speed. However, to remain compatible with existing infrastructure, busses stay at 400 Hz when connected to ground power.

Aircraft use 400 Hz AC because it's more efficient and makes for lighter transformers than lower mains frequency. But the higher the frequency, the more losses with distance. There's no good reason to use 50 or 60 Hz on a plane, except for passenger convenience, since the distances are all quite short. International power lines tend to use DC to minimize the losses.
Why don't planes? DC is harder to use: you need complex power electronics with controller to efficiently convert DC-to-DC. They've become common in the PC era, and are far lighter than transformers, but modern aircraft have become standardized before that (the 737 is from the 1960s). DC-DC is the future, but it's still the future.
While at that, most modern electronics use switching mode power supplies, which don't care much about the frequency. They convert AC to DC first, and can even run on direct current. Most modern power supplies will work fine with 100V or 300V, 0 Hz or 50 Hz or 400 Hz. Many flight crews routinely use these outlets to charge their laptops and phones. So 400 Hz works just fine.

Disclaimer: Don't try this at home (not that you can), and especially don't try this on a commercial flight. It may only be 1 in 100 devices that won't work on 400 Hz, but in-flight isn't the time to check if you've drawn the short straw.
The reverse also doesn't work. Do not try to power airplane equipment from a 60 Hz outlet. 400 Hz transformers are smaller than 60 Hz ones, and will overheat or short the power input if fed 60 Hz under load.

This may be true for most aircraft, but the A380 doesn't use 400 Hz AC. It uses variable frequency generators.
